# Kaminari pagination scope problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, pagination, kaminari

In Kaminari, this works:

```
<%= paginate @posts %>
```

But if I do something like:

```
<%= paginate @user.posts %>
```

I get

```
undefined method `current_page' for #<Class:0x58378e0>
```

How do I fix this? I heard inherited_resources helped, but I don't know how to use it to fix this bug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because in the first version `@posts` was probably the result of running something like

```
   @posts = Post.page(2).per(50)
```

So Kaminari returned an array like object, which `paginate` helper method expects.

When you call `@user.posts` directly you are in fact just loading a plain old ActiveRecord association.

The short answer is that you need to let Kaminari generate the variable you are in fact using with the `paginate` helper method

Comment: I have a noob question, how would I set it up so that @posts is filtered by a username? Like, something similar to: 

posts = Post.find(user).page(params[:page]).per(5)

Comment: nvm, i fixed it:  @posts = @user_on_page.posts.page(params[:page]).per(5)